# Performance difference between Iterator Class and foreach construct

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrentmodification

I have the following code running, but I sometimes get some sort of concurrency exception when running it.

```
ArrayList<Mob> carriers = new ArrayList<Mob>();
ArrayList<Mob> mobs = new ArrayList<Mob>();
...
for (Mob carrier : carriers){
    for (Mob mob : mobs){
        checkInfections (carrier, mob);
    } 
}
```

I refactored it to solve the concurrency problem, but it did lead me to a question. Would there be a difference in performance if I change the for construct to an Iterator pattern? What's the access level difference between the foreach construct and the Iterator class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is largely syntactic sugar except that an `Iterator` can remove items from the `Collection` it is iterating. Technically, enhanced `for` loops allow you to loop over anything that's `Iterable`, which at a minimum includes both `Collection`s and arrays.

Don't worry about performance differences. Such micro-optimization is an irrelevant distraction. If you need to remove items as you go, use an `Iterator`. Otherwise `for` loops tend to be used more just because they're more readable ie:

```
for (String s : stringList) { ... }
```

vs:

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = stringList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
  String s = iter.next();
  ...
}
```

Comment: To be super pedantic, enhanced `for` loops allow you to loop over anything that's `Iterable` or an array, and arrays aren't `Iterable`.

Comment: @ColinD I mention this in the first paragraph.

Comment: I was being pedantic about the way you phrased it in the first paragraph, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes the new style `for` is implemented in terms of iterators by the compiler, so there will be no difference if you do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The "some sort of concurrency exception" you're talking about is most likely `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. You get this because you cannot change the list while you are iterating over it; if you do that, the iterator will notice and throw this exception.

If you need to remove elements from a list while iterating over it, then do it through the `remove()` method on the iterator, for example:

```
List<String> list = ...; // wherever you get this

for (Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    String s = iter.next();
    if (...) {
        iter.remove(); // Remove element through iterator
    }
}
```

(Note: You can't use the foreach syntax for the loop in this case, because you need explicit access to the iterator).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Iterator(interface) only on collections like List, Set & Queue but for each loop cab be used for everything which is iterable like Collections and Array. And for each loop is more readable..