# Which of these methods is most effective when I traverse a List?

Tags: java, performance

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

1 method:

```
for(int i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

2 method:

```
for(T t : list) {
  System.out.println(t);
}
```

3 method:

```
Iterator<T> it = list.iterator();     
while(it.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Comment: What did you mean by "effective"? Are you after performance, readability or best practice?  I'd definitely prefer optimizing simplicity rather performance unless you know there is a problem.

Comment: `int i = list.length - 1` should be `int i = list.size() - 1`.  Your syntax is correct for an array.

Comment: Note attempting to access arrays in reverse order is likely to be slower than in forward order. The benefit of combining the decrement with compare saves an instruction, but for some time now register-only instructions have been really cheap. Hardware cache and memory read are optimised for forward reads. Also Oracle HotSpot, and probably others, do not have equivalent optimisations for backwards iterations, because they are rarely used (and programs that do use them as an attempt at optimisation almost certainly have other bigger problems).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The efficiency is unlikely to be significant - certainly `System.out.println` is much more likely to be the bottleneck in your particular example.

The second approach (enhanced for loop) is the most *readable* however. Note that the three approaches don't do the same thing - the first one will iterate from the *end* rather than the *start*. Getting the right behaviour almost always trumps running a teeny, tiny bit faster. The more readable your code is, the more likely you are to get it right.

Go for readability, measure the performance of your app, and *if* it becomes a problem, micro-optimise the bottlenecks (continuing to measure at every step).

EDIT: I was basing this answer on the first line of the question, showing an `ArrayList<T>` being used.

If you want an answer for *any* `List<T>` then there simply isn't an accurate answer. `List<T>` doesn't offer any guarantees about complexity. It doesn't say how fast you should expect `get` to be, nor how fast you should expect an iterator to be. You *could* be using an implementation which has good random access, but a painfully slow iterator. It's unlikely, but it would still be a valid `List<T>`.

In short: if you're concerned about the efficiency, you need to know what kind of list you're using. *In general* iterating it likely to be reasonably efficient, and random access *may or may not* be efficient. (It may be more efficient than iterating, but it's unlikely to be *significantly* more efficient.) In practice, my experience is that in most applications you actually have enough knowledge to make a reasonable judgement... but I'd still usually code for readability first.

As others have pointed out, if you *do* want to use random access to get at the elements, then it would be worth ensuring that your list implements the [`RandomAccess`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface too.

Comment: See the answer offered by @jarnbjo for an explanation of the downvote.

Comment: @Tim: Despite the first line of the question? Surely there's at least a certain amount of ambiguity here...

Comment: I reversed my downvote. Thanks for editing. I think it is safe to assume that the OP did not realize the significance of the first line in his post and the question specifies List.

Answer (score 5):

The first method will be much slower if you have a long list without random access support. E.g. calling get(1000000) on a LinkedList will have to loop through 1000000 elements from the beginning of the list to reach the 1000000th element. The second and third methods ought to be equivalent.

If it's relevant in your case, List implementations which offer constant time random access to its elements should imlement the java.util.RandomAccess marker interface. At least the List implementations in the standard API do.

Comment: The question itself (" ... when I want to traversal a List?") is in the title and does not specify which List implementation Chris means.

Comment: @jarnbjo: So all the relevant information for a question has to be in the title?

Comment: @skeet: Where did I write that a question has to be in the title? In this case it is: "Which methods is the most effective when I want to traversal a List?" You are right that the example code actually uses an ArrayList, but that is not what Chris asked about.

Comment: @jarbjo: I think it's reasonable to take the code provided into account when answering the question, that's all... (Not that I'm claiming anything you've written is wrong, mind you.)

Comment: I don't know if the author is aware of such difference between LinkedList and ArrayList...

Answer (score 5):

Method 1 is very unlikely to be the best one as it has no readability or performance advantage over the others.

If you want to keep track of the index, consider using a `ListIterator` instead of an `Iterator`, e.g.

```
ListIterator<T> it = list.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    T t = it.next;
    int index = it.previousIndex();
    System.out.printf("%d => %s%n", index, t);
}
```

As others have pointed out, method 3 is equivalent to method 2 unless you want to remove elements from the list during iteration.

If profiling shows that the list's `get(int)` method or the iterator's `next()` or `hasNext()` is a performance bottleneck (very rare but it can happen), consider replacing the list with an array (you can still use the for-each syntax, similar to method 2.)

Answer (score 2):

#### On `RandomAccess`

[`java.util.ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) implements [`RandomAccess`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html). The documentation is clear on what this means:

> Marker interface used by `List` implementations to indicate that they support fast (generally constant time) random access. [...] As a rule of thumb, a `List` implementation should implement this interface if, for typical instances of the class, this loop:
>
> ```
> for (int i=0, n=list.size(); i < n; i++)
>      list.get(i);
> ```
>
> runs faster than this loop:
>
> ```
> for (Iterator i=list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
>      i.next();
> ```

Thus, for a `List` that *properly* `implements RandomAccess`, the indexed-`get` is faster.

Note however that this is *NOT* true for, say, a `LinkedList`, in which the above code exhibits quadratic performance. This is because `LinkedList` does not permit constant-time random access; that is, `get` is linear for `LinkedList`.

Note that even if the indexed-`get` is faster, it'll only be by a constant factor. Profile first to see if this optimization attempt is worth it.

#### Related questions

- [When to use `LinkedList` over `ArrayList`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

---

#### On `for-each` vs `Iterator` loop

There is no significant difference between the performance of these two constructs that you should concern yourself with. The `for-each` loop is much more readable but is applicable in more limited scenarios, and thus precisely in those scenarios is where you should use them. When the `for-each` loop is not applicable, then use an `Iterator` loop.

A quote from *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 46: Prefer `for-each` loops to traditional `for` loops*:

> The `for-each` loop, introduced in release 1.5, gets rid of the clutter
>   and the opportunity for error by hiding the iterator or index variable
>   completely. The resulting idiom applies equally to collections and arrays:
>
> ```
> // The preferred idiom for iterating over collections and arrays
> for (Element e : elements) {
>     doSomething(e);
> }
> ```
>
> When you see the colon (:), read it as "in." Thus, the loop above reads as
>   "for each element `e` in elements." Note that there is no performance penalty
>   for using the `for-each` loop, even for arrays. In fact, it may offer a slight
>   performance advantage over an ordinary `for` loop in some circumstances, as it
>   computes the limit of the array index only once.

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/for-each loop](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

#### Related questions

- [Java foreach efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904582/java-foreach-efficiency)
- [Performance difference between `Iterator` Class and foreach construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183153/performance-difference-between-iterator-class-and-foreach-construct)
- [Performance: Iterating through a `List` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642004/performance-iterating-through-a-list-in-java)
- [traditional for loop vs `Iterator` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879255/traditional-for-loop-vs-iterator-in-java)
- [Is there a performance difference between a for loop and a for-each loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256859/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-a-for-loop-and-a-for-each-loop)

Comment: Since which version of Java, this RandomAccess Marker Interface introduced ?

Comment: @Bragboy: documentation says 1.4. The `@since` is a standard javadoc tag.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no explanation on what exactly is meant by effectiveness, I will answer from the position of what should be preferred.

I would prefer **the 2nd method as the most readable**.

Why: until the program is written, you don't know, where the bottlenecks are going to be. This is why premature optimization is unlikely to yield substantial results. But readability of the code is always relevant, so I would choose the second variant.

Answer (score 1):

If you concern about performance, it depend on the implementation of List. 
With `ArrayList`, the first is the fastest. It is as fast as:

```
for(int i = 0, n=list.size(); i < n; i++) {
  System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

That's because `ArrayList` buffers an array inside. When you call `objArrayList.get(i)`, it will return `objArrayList.buffArray[i]`.

For each and Iterator is the same. Hence equally slow

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer method 2, unless you need to call something on the iterator object (like `iterator.remove()`) in which case I would prefer method 3.

<strike>The only case I would use method 1 is if I needed to keep a track of the indexes in the loop anyway (and then only in the case of a `List` that is a dense array-like implentation, like `ArrayList`).</strike>

**Update:**
In line with comments/other answers, I now prefer `ListIterator` when iterating through a List keeping track of indexes.  Leaving method 1 only useful for something that cannot be achieved through any of the other means.

Comment: See the answer offered by @jarnbjo for an explanation of the downvote.

Comment: Consider `ListIterator` if you want to keep track of the index.  See my answer.

Comment: Great point, not something I've used before, but definitely prefer it to the old-style for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/while-loop-for-loop-and-iterator-performance-test-java/) comparison perhaps it helps you forward

Answer (score 0):

Many factors will influence the measure.

First of all, notice that your second and third alternatives are bytecode-equivalent. Indeed, the Java [enhanced for loop](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) is a syntactic sugar, which means that, in your case, the second alternative will look, after compilation, **exactly** like your third alternative.

The most obvious one is the chosen implementation. If you do this test with `LinkedList` rather than with `ArrayList`, you'll find that, obviously, iterators are faster than random array access. You'll even find, under some conditions, that iterating over a `LinkedList` is faster than iterating over an `ArrayList`.And you now what ? In most of your code, you'll swap with no reason from one to the other impplemenation.

As a consequence, as a general rule of thumb, for both readability and code efficiency, I tend to always use the second method.

Comment: The second and third methods are actually not generating equivalent bytecode. The temporary assignment to the local variable t (in the second method) will remain as such in the compiled bytecode, while the bytecode generated for the third method will leave the result of it.next() on the stack and use it directly as an argument to the println call.